# If the coefficient of $x$ in the penultimate term of the remainder is 1280, what is the value of $n$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

$$\frac{(x+n)^n+(x+2)^n+(n+2)^n}{x^2-(n+2)x+2n}$$

From: Lumbreras Editors

---

I tried using the remainder theorem without success

Comment: What have you tried? Have you factored the denominator?

Comment: Could you elaborate on what is question ? I can not understand things in title.

Comment: Can you show what you've done with RFT? It should work pretty directly.

Comment: I made a correction to the numerator

Answer (score 1):

(Fill in the gaps as needed. If you're stuck, show your work and explain what you've done.)

The numerator is $ f_n(x) = (x+n)^n  + (x+2)^n + (n+2)^n$.
The denominator is $ g_n(x) = (x-n)(x-2)$.
Let $f_n(x) = g_n(x) p(x) + ax + b $, then we're after the value of $a$.

$f_n(n) = (2n)^n + (n+2)^n + (n+2)^n = na + b$.
$f_n(2) = (2+n)^n + 4^n + (n+2)^n = 2a+b$.

Then $ a = \dfrac{ f_n(n) - f_n(2) } { n - 2 }  = \dfrac{(2n)^n-4^n}{n-2}=1280$

Hence $ n = \ldots $

---

Note: I'm interpreting "penultimate term of the remainder" as "the coefficient of $x$ in $ax+b$", as opposed to "the coefficient of $x$ in $p(x)$".

Comment: I guess the same